# How to list the packages installed to pip in virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

## Introduction

I have a virtual environment I am using as a project interpreter inside of `pycharm`. The virtual environment name is `myenv`.

## Activation

I am on a windows machine, so to activate I do the following:

```
C:<path\to\myenvparent> myenv\Scripts\activate.bat
(myenv) C:<path\to\myenvparent>
```

Great, the virtual environment is activated. This is now where I normally `pip install` packages to the environment.

## Pip List

I want to create a `requirements.txt` file so that another person working on the project easily have a working environment like mine on their computer with one easy command `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
I have made this happen before, but am confused at what is now occuring:

```
(myenv) C:<path\to\myenvparent> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.3
setuptools 39.0.1
virtualenv 16.7.2
C:<path\to\myenvparent>
```

For **some reason**, it lists out just these things. When I do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, the contents of requirements.txt says *virtualenv==16.7.2*.

## Question

Why is pip list and pip freeze behaving like this for me? Have I switched some setting since I did this last?

Comment: Did you install packages after you activated it?

Comment: Yeah it has a lot of packages, it is running my project. e.g. numpy, pandas, scipy

Comment: Then it sounds like the `pip` executable you are using is NOT the `pip` executable in your virtual environment. To be safe, use pip as a module---that way the pip that gets called is the one with your environment. `python -m pip <pip args>`

Comment: When I do `python -m pip list` it gives the same thing it did from the post.

Comment: But `python yourscript.py` works with third party packages? Clearly, the environment that Pycharm is running in is not the same as your command line one. This isn't hard to remedy, but you haven't really given enough info to help.

Comment: Project Interpretor: `Python 3.6 (MyEnv) C:\path\to\MyEnv\Scripts\python.exe` is what pycharm says. I can see the packages I have listed out in the window there, e.g. matplotlib, numpy, pandas, etc.

Comment: Do you get the same python executable from `where python` in CMD with the venv activated? I think that's the right command in Windows..if not, search up how to find location of an executable in the command prompt.

Comment: No. When I say `where python` when the virtual env is activated I get two things back: `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe` and
`C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`. This is the SAME two things I get back when I say `where python` from outside. It appears that I am not actually accessing my virtual env when its activated now. What is going on here?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help much as I don't use Windows. I would run through the Python venv tutorial and create a new env to try it all out: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/. Note that the check at the end is the same as I suggested---activate your venv and run `where python` to be sure the python shown is inside your virtual environment.

Comment: I created a new environment recently, and it works great. As long as I keep an up to date `requirements.txt` file, then when the `venv` decides to behave like this it wont take time to make a new one. Thank you for the help. Ps. I learned on Unix so Windows behavior is fairly new to me.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. This isn't a typical issue just so you're aware. venvs are generally smooth sailing! :)